# Backslash preservation with Docker, echo, and Perl

Tags: bash, perl, docker

I am using perl to call `docker exec` in a very specific way to echo information into `/etc/bashrc` within a Docker container.

I have two Perl variables that I need interpolated into the echo command. `$c_name` will usually have a value of `test1` or something.`$net_ip` will usually have a value of `192.168.0.x`

```
my $prompt = '[\A][' . $c_name . '][' . $net_ip . '][\w]\n\$ ';
`docker exec --privileged $c_name bash -c "echo -e 'PS1=$prompt' >> /etc/bashrc"`;
```

This concatentation effort is about the fourth shot at this. I've also tried

```
`docker exec --privileged $c_name bash -c "echo -e PS1='[\A][$c_name][$net_ip][\w]\n\$ ' >> /etc/bashrc"`;
```

Neither of these work. When I do a `docker exec -it test1 /bin/bash` I get a prompt that looks like this:

```
bash: $: command not found
[A][test1][192.168.0.13][w]
```

with my `/etc/bashrc` looking like the following:

```
PS1=[\A][test1][192.168.0.13][\w]
$
```

Now this is kinda-correct. It looks like it didn't escape `\n` and `\$` That is a problem. But what's more concerning is that the prompt is not respecting the `\A` and `\w` there. Even when I do `source /etc/bashrc` from within the container, I'm still getting the error message above from Bash and my prompt stays the same. Is there some weird interaction with Docker and $PS1 I don't know about?

What I want is at the end of my `/etc/bashrc` I want this line to exist, verbatim, with interpolated Perl $vars:

```
[\A][$c_name][$net_ip][\w]\n\$
```

which, after Perl interpretation, might look like:

```
[\A][test_container][10.0.0.2][/home/docker]
$
```

I've tried other attempts as well, such as trying to escape the backslashes with double `\\` (e.g. `[\\A]`, however, either Perl complains about not recognizing escaped characters ("Unrecognized escape option at $linenumber) or it simply has the same results as above where the backslashes are not placed into /etc/bashrc.

Note that when I'm in the container and I execute:

```
export PS1='[\A][test1][192.168.0.13][\w]\n\$ '
```

then the prompt is correct:

```
[20:26][test1][192.168.0.13][/]
#
```

Comment: I realise that. You've spoiled it now!

Comment: Why are you using backticks in void context? Why not just use `system` and avoid one level of interpretation (the shell)?

Comment: Is `system` a better practice? I didn't have a particular reason for using one over the other.

Comment: `\n` is expanded by `echo -e`. Why are you using `-e` here?

Comment: You're missing quotes around the value. Without them, `\A` is interpreted by the shell as plain `A` during assignment to `PS1`.

Comment: You should build this up in layers. First edit `/etc/bashrc` until you get a line that works. Then create a shell command that correctly adds that line to `/etc/bashrc`. Then get that command to work in `docker exec`. Finally run that command from Perl.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would feed the prompt to `docker` via standard input, rather than use `bash` as you are. Then you need only run one command, `tee -a /etc/bashrc`; it will inherit its standard input from `docker`, whose standard input is the file handle `$fh`.

```
open my $fh, "|-", "docker exec --privileged '$c_name' tee -a /etc/bashrc";
printf $fh "PS1=$prompt\n";
close $fh;
```